# Trying to fasten a steel tube to an exhaust manifold

Tags: ford, exhaust, f100, exhaust-manifold

Does anyone have experience trying to fasten/connect a small diameter steel tube to a cast iron exhaust manifold?

I'm working on a 1979 Ford F-100 with a 300 CID/4.9L inline 6 engine.  Part of the emissions system includes a steel tube that fits into a small, drilled hole on the exhaust manifold.  The other end of that tube hooks up to a vacuum hose that then connects to a temperature sensor inside the air cleaner assembly.  This is part of the control system for the flapper valve located in the air intake throat.

My problem is I can't get the tube to stay in the hole in the exhaust manifold.  As best as I can tell it is a press fit only - no threads, no fittings or clamping mechanism, etc.  But while I can push the tube into the hole, it always falls out very easily.

I've looked at high temperature JB Weld, but I don't think it will last on the high temperatures, an exhaust manifold can get to (500-1000 deg. F., as I understand).

So, are there any better ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: great question.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Comment: I'd suggest welding/brazing it in place. But really it depends on the type of cast iron. See http://www.hobartwelders.com/weldtalk/showthread.php?6-Welding-Cast-iron-to-mild-steel&s=bcc99438df038a3dffe83c09e4e4f082, http://www.lincolnelectric.com/en-us/support/welding-how-to/Pages/welding-cast-iron-detail.aspx, http://www.weldguru.com/CastIron.html

Comment: I've thought about bagging the entire emissions system, including the flapper valve, but in Las Vegas I have to pass annual emissions checks, or limit my mileage to less than 5000 miles a year - which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get rid of that flapper air cleaner system, unless you live somewhere with a winter that insists you have it.  Plug the manifold hole.  OR...
2. Get a pro to braze the riser tube, most likely done while still on the truck.  OR...
3. Get a calm and mellow person to *carefully* drill/tap the exhaust manifold, to install a compression to male NPT adapter fitting with a metal ferrule.

Those things were always a disaster.  And that accordion hoses always popped off and rotted away.  Emissions really wasn't an issue, so if you can get it started cold and allow a bit extra warm_up, you should be fine with a "scorched earth" #1 type of solution.

Answer (score 1):

Cast iron drills and taps about as easy as hard wood. Then thread in a tapered fitting for your hose. As a metallurgist , brazing seems like a challenge I don't want.